# Can we write sql query in mysql custum function

Tags: mysql

Can we write mysql query with in custom function of mysql

Please take a look in my example

```
// here **price** is a input parameter 

BEGIN
  DECLARE profit DECIMAL(9,2);
  SET all  =  select count(*) from users; // let the output is 5 
  SET profit = price-all ;
  RETURN profit;
END
```

Comment: Profit minus the number of users?  What are you trying to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course you can do. Just create your function correctly and call it like
These function are called [User defined functions](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/)

[**SQLFiddle Working Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c705d9/1). Currently sqlfiddle is not executing my select query.
 Test it like

Code:

```
   create function calc(price float)  RETURNS float
   begin
      DECLARE profit float;
      DECLARE varallr int;
      set varallr = (Select count(*) from users);
      SET profit = price-varallr ;
      RETURN profit;
   end
```

Remember you need to use `//` as delimiter. [image]

```
   select calc(5); //gives you 3
```

Comment: Please check the sql fifdle demo link. Its working and anybody can see it What do you exactly mean by not working? Fuction is not getting created or you are getting some error in `select calc()`